# how to conver date like 01 mar 2011 to only mar 2011

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to conver date like 01 mar 2011 to only mar 2011 in javascript or jquery

Answer (score 2):

You could split it on  .

```
var date = '01 mar 2011';

var dateTokens = date.split(' ');

dateTokens.shift();

var newDate = dateTokens.join(' ');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/wEyqk/).

Alternatively you could use a regex...

```
var newDate = date.replace(/\d+ /, '');

document.body.innerHTML = newDate;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/5czSD/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have this as a string you can`substr`-it from the first space onwards. Like this:

```
var d = "01 Mar 2011";
var formatted = d.substr(d.indexOf(" "), d.length);
```

Otherwise (if it's not a string) you'll need to use the `Date` object.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the others:

```
function trimDate(s) {
  return s.replace(/^[\d ]+/,'');
}
```

A more efficient (though longer) version:

```
var trimDate = (function() {
  var re = /^[\d ]+/;
  return function (s) {
    return s.replace(re, '');
  }
}());

alert(trimDate('1 mar 2011')); // mar 2011
```